# Display message 'user typing...' to everyone, including sender, if I am typing a message, VUE JS and socket.io

Tags: sockets, vue.js, socket.io

I am using vuejs and socket.io in my application. The task is this: if I type a message in a dialogue with the user, display a message to both the interlocutor and myself, that I am typing a message.
How can I implement this?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it would require writing a measurably long tutorial to answer this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Socket.io gives you lots of options to send messages across the board. What I always found very helpful is the `Emit cheatsheet` from the official docs (https://socket.io/docs/emit-cheatsheet/).

Here are some of the methods on how to broadcast messages to all clients **including** sender.

```js
io.on('connect', onConnect);

function onConnect(socket) {

  // sending to all clients in 'chat' room, including sender
  io.in('chat').emit('typing', 'User xy is typing');

  // sending to all clients in namespace 'chatNamespace', including sender
  io.of('chatNamespace').emit('typing', 'User xy is typing');

  // sending to a specific room in a specific namespace, including sender
  io.of('chatNamespace').to('chat').emit('typing', 'User xy is typing');

}
```

Now this of course are just example methods. You would need to wrap this into your own business logic and probably register some socket event listeners to get this going.